# Flutter Riverpod using ProviderListener in HookWidget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In previous versions of `Riverpod` package for `Flutter` i could use `ProviderListener` simply into `HookWidget` and now it's depricated for new versions and i can't found any documentation about that to know how can i use that again

```dart
ProviderListener<NetworkRequestState<LoginResponseStructure>>(
provider: loginProvider,
onChange: (BuildContext context,
    NetworkRequestState<LoginResponseStructure> loginListener) {
  loginListener.when(idle: () {
    enableTextField.value = true;
  }, loading: () {
    ...
  }, success: (value) {
    final LoginResponseStructure _res = value as LoginResponseStructure;
    if (_res.statusCode == 1) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }, error: (error, stackTrace) {
    enableTextField.value = true;
  });
},
```

deprecated error message:

> 'ProviderListener' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use
> WidgetRef.listen instead.

for example:

```dart
class SignUP extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: DefaultColors.$lightBlue,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child:
          ProviderListener<NetworkRequestState<LoginResponseStructure>>(
            provider: loginProvider,
            onChange: (BuildContext context,
                NetworkRequestState<LoginResponseStructure> loginListener) {
              loginListener.when(idle: () {
                enableTextField.value = true;
              }, loading: () {
              }, success: (value) {
              }, error: (error, stackTrace) {
              });
            },
            child: Scaffold(
                ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mentioned in the error message. You could simply use `ref.listen` as a hook. Refer to the docs [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-reflisten-to-react-to-a-provider-change).

Example:

*Note: Haven't tested but this is what your example will look like*

```dart
class SignUp extends HookConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen<NetworkRequestState<LoginResponseStructure>>(
      loginProvider, (NetworkRequestState? previousState, NetworkRequestState newState) {
        loginListener.when...;
     });

    return Container(
      color: DefaultColors.$lightBlue,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: ...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```